# Cropping long text inside a link

Tags: html, css

I've created a container which will be holding a couple links. Each link has two things:

1. Text
2. A download link (this can even change later on to an image)

I am able to crop the text when we resize the browser but not completely to what i want.

*This text doesn't need to get cropped as it can fit to screen*
[image: This text doesn't need to get cropped as it can fit to screen]

*Text here is getting cropped but it is pushing the span within the link down*
[image: Text here is getting cropped but it is pushing the span within the link down]

Is there any way to avoid the "Download" `span` from getting pushed down? So basically the text crop for the text in the link should start when it overflows the `span`.
Any ideas on how i can achieve this? Please note that i want the whole line (paragraph tag) to be the link as this is going to be used mostly on mobile devices.

PS: i don't want to use javascript, as i prefer it to be purely with CSS. If that is not possible a short jQuery solution can be used for it.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/fdyt2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="box-white">
    <p><a href="#"> Short  <span>Download<span class="arrow">&gt;</span></span></a>
    </p>
    <p><a href="#"> Oh My God this description is more like an essay someone do something about this! <span>Download<span class="arrow">&gt;</span></span></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-white {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #B4B7BB;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.box-white p {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B4B7BB;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box-white p a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.box-white p span {
    color: #4C556C;
    float: right;
    font-weight: normal;
}
a {
    color: #0085d5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swapping the order of your description and the download-link-spans should do the trick: Place the float-right span *before* the actual description.

Based on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdyt2/2/

```
<p><a href="#"> <span>Download<span class="arrow">&gt;</span></span> Oh My God this description is more like an essay someone do something about this! </a>
```

Using the left margin of the span you can control the distance between the end of the cropped text and the download link.

Here is a screenshot of the result in Chrome:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Am I missing something? What browser are you using? In Chrome neither original fiddle nor this one does the cropping

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Is your browser supporting the text-overflow: ellipsis property? http://caniuse.com/text-overflow

Comment: @Gigo I assumed Chrome 29 for Windows supported everything.  Yet only another answer below by Chad shows cropping in mine.

Comment: Strange, I'm also using Chrome on windows and it looks totally fine.

Comment: Ah I think I got it. I was looking at it at full resolution. I assumed it would always crop to specific fixed length. But there was plenty of space and full text was showing. I resized browser window to make it smaller and now see the effect.

Comment: @Gigo sometimes the answer is just infront of you and you can't see it. Thanks for this Gigo :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning. Try adding the following:

```
.box-white p a {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.box-white p a > span {
    color: #4C556C;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdyt2/3/)

Comment: absolute positioning is not an option as its behavior is not what i am looking for . + Your example is not working correctly when resizing the browser.